# No of rows to be displayed

Tags: sql-server

I have 100 records. I want to display only 10 rows of that record default or by specifying the number by using procedure

Comment: is the question about SQL-Server (or some other DBMS, like MySQL, Postgres, Oracle...)? Please edit and clarify. It would also be good to put some details on the question about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of records to return by using TOP

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table
```

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is like shopping blindfold.

Comment: Of course, but how do you select top a piece of string

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @CraigEfrein said with one minor change.  I wouldn't use dynamic SQL in the stored procedure.  You can pass a variable into the TOP command.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_return_top_n_rows
@num_rows as integer
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 SELECT TOP(@num_rows) * FROM mydatabase..mytable 

END

-- execute the stored procedure, specifying a total result of 10 rows 
exec sp_return_top_n_rows 10
```

Comment: please `ORDER BY`

Answer (score -2):

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE sp_return_top_n_rows
             BEGIN
                     SELECT  DISTINCT *
                      FROM    table
                       LIMIT 10

              END
```

Comment: You should explain your answer instead of simply posting code.  Also, `LIMIT 10` won't work in SQL Server.